# java - como tomar una foto de un resultado de google en tiempo real

Tags: android, autocompletar

Tengo un **autoCompleteTextView** de cuidades y quiero que al escribir y salgan los resultados estos esten con el siguiente formato: una foto de esa cuidad y el nombre de esta.

Adjunto los codigos de lo que tengo hecho:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(context, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, Cities);

        txtInputSource.setThreshold(1);
        txtInputDestiny.setThreshold(1);

        txtInputSource.setAdapter(adapter);//setting the adapter data into the AutoCompleteTextView
        txtInputDestiny.setAdapter(adapter);//setting the adapter data into the AutoCompleteTextView
```

Esto funciona bien. Como hago para crear un adaptador de este tipo personalizado y cargar la foto?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero obtener algo como eso. Con una imagen de la cuidad obtenida de una consulta a Google es eso posible?

**EDIT:**
En caso de no ser posible hacer exactamente lo que pido hay alguna forma que utilizando alguna API de Google maps pueda lograr mi resultado? Obtener exactamente la dirección y una foto de dicha cuidad?

Comment: Si necesitan que agregue otros códigos me lo dicen. El adaptador que tengo es el default por eso solo adjunto la parte en la que lo instancio. Espero que me puedan ayudar

Comment: Hasta donde tengo conocimiento eso no es posible dado a que las imagenes de google estan almacenadas en diferentes servidores, no son imagenes del mismo google (obviamente google puede hacer eso pues porque es google xD) lo que necesitarias seria un servidor de imagenes en la cual tenga una URL fija y solamente cambie una porcion por el tipo de imagen que estes buscando algo como: http://tu.servidor.com/imagenes?busqueda La forma en que pudieras realizar eso seria mediante un servicio web que devuelva las imagenes y tu las ingreses en tu listView.

Comment: Yo para Katalon Studio (una herramienta de test) utilizo una librería que se llama ashot-1.5.4.jar (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ru.yandex.qatools.ashot/ashot/1.5.4) y te permite sacar hardcopys de pantalla. No me queda claro si tu aplicación es una app Android o de escritorio.

Comment: Para realizar lo que deseas puedes utilizar la API de Google llamada Google Places al habilitar esta api puedes traer nombres de ciudades de google junto con sus fotos estos son algunos de los links que te pueden servir: [Youtube Google Places](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8hSRml50u1o) [Google Place Photos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31499955/android-getting-google-places-photos-and-api-calls) [Google Photos Documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/photos)

Answer (score 0):

SobreEscribe el metodo getView del ArrayAdapter.

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        return miVista;
    }
```

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, esto no soluciona lo que se pregunta, la pregunta al parecer es "demasiado amplia", te sugerimos revisar [ask], recuerda que las aclaraciones se realizan como comentario, saludos.

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia, pero el que decidí sobre la respuesta es el que pregunta. Y no puedo comentar por las políticas de la web.

Comment: Revisa por favor [¿Por qué necesito 50 puntos de reputación para comentar? ¿Qué alternativa tengo?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/586/por-qu%c3%a9-necesito-50-puntos-de-reputaci%c3%b3n-para-comentar-qu%c3%a9-alternativa-tengo).

Comment: @OsAndNoTi gracias x tu respuesta pero como decía Jorgesys no es lo que necesito. Muchas gracias de todas formas

Comment: Esta respuesta no responde a lo que se pregunta, considera modificarla o eliminarla, saludos.